# get checkbox value without using Ext.getCmp

Tags: javascript, scope, extjs4.1

I am trying to get value of this checkbox

```
 Ext.define('myRoot.myExtApp.myForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    layout: {
      type: 'vbox',
      align: 'stretch'
    },
    scope: this,
    constructor: function() {
       this.callParent(arguments);

       this.myFieldSet = Ext.create('Ext.form.FieldSet', {
         scope: this,
         columnWidth: 0.5,
         collapsible: false,
         defaultType: 'textfield',
         layout: {
             type: 'hbox', align: 'stretch'
         }
       });

       this.mySecondForm = Ext.create('myRoot.myExtApp.myForm2', {
         scope: this,
         listener: this,
         margin: '1 3 0 0'
       });
       this.myCheckBox = Ext.create('Ext.form.Checkbox', {
           scope: this,
           //id: 'myCheckBox',
           boxLabel: 'Active',
           name: 'Active',
           checked: true,
           horizontal: true
       });

       this.myFieldSet.add(this.mySecondForm);
       this.myFieldSet.add(this.myCheckBox);

       this.add(this.myFieldSet);
     }
 });
```

As you can see I have another form

```
Ext.define('myRoot.myExtApp.myForm2', {
```

where I have a handler, that should get the value of the checkbox from "myForm"

How can I get the value of my checkbox from Form2 without using Ext.getCmp? I know I can get the value of the checkbox if I do

```
Ext.getCmp('myCheckBox').getValue();
```

but using

```
this.myCheckBox.getValue();
```

gives me undefined error.

**UPDATE** - with Wared suggestion I tried this inside myForm2

```
this.temp=Ext.create('myRoot.myExtApp.myForm'), {});
var tempV = this.temp.myCheckBox.getValue();
```

I was able to get the value but I get the same true value even if I uncheck the box

Comment: You haven't posted enough of your structure, we need to see how it all fits together.

Comment: To extend on Evan's response - it's impossible to tell what's the scope of `this` in `this.myCheckBox`.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli, Thank you for taking time to look at my post. Please see my update. I have edited it with my complete structure.

Comment: @Izhaki... hi Izhaki, please see my updated post. Would that help?

Comment: Could you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? That could really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you worry about performance loss due to excessive use of component queries. A nice trick to minimize component queries could be to define a new method inside a closure in order to cache the result of the first `getCmp` call. Wrapping the definition of the method inside a closure allows to avoid using global scope or a useless class property.

```
getMyCmp: function (cmp) { 
    // "cmp" does not exist outside this function
    return function () { 
        return cmp = cmp || Ext.getCmp('#myCmp'); 
    }; 
}()
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be :

```
myRoot.myExtApp.myForm.myCheckBox.getValue();
```

**Beware, wrong answer. See comments below for a valid solution.**

Comment: @wared... thank you... but I still get the undefined error. The other thing I tried is on myForm2... I did this.temp=Ext.create('myRoot.myExtApp.myForm'), {}); and var tempV = this.temp.myCheckBox.getValue();... and I get the value but I get the same true value even if I uncheck the box

Comment: Sorry, I'm totally wrong... "myRoot.myExtApp.myForm" refers to the class while we need an instance. I need more details to help you. How about the code where your forms are instanciated?

Comment: Thanks wared... You are partially correct. I had to make sure I declared parent: this and on my extended class all I had to do was... this.parent.myCheckBox.getValue();